# How to copy a JSON data to the clipboard with a button

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a JSON data where i should copy the JSON data to clipboard with a button click

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "kinesis:RemoveTagsFromStream",
        "ecr:TagResource",
        "ecs:TagResource",
        "elasticache:RemoveTagsFromResource",
        "fsx:UntagResource",
        "acm:AddTagsToCertificate",
        "states:UntagResource",
        "elasticache:AddTagsToResource",
        "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
        "datapipeline:RemoveTags",
        "secretsmanager:TagResource",
        "logs:ListTagsLogGroup",
        "fsx:TagResource",
        "cloudfront:UntagResource",
        "logs:UntagLogGroup",
        "dms:RemoveTagsFromResource",
        "kinesisvideo:UntagStream",
        "sqs:UntagQueue",
        "elasticbeanstalk:AddTags",
        "ssm:AddTagsToResource",
        "resource-groups:Tag",
        "ecr:UntagResource",
        "datapipeline:AddTags",
        "ecs:UntagResource",
        "transfer:TagResource",
        "elasticfilesystem:CreateTags",
        "events:TagResource",
        "events:UntagResource",
        "dax:ListTags",
        "ec2:CreateTags",
        "workspaces:CreateTags",
        "kinesis:AddTagsToStream",
        "iot:TagResource",
        "cloudwatch:UntagResource",
        "mq:CreateTags",
        "sagemaker:AddTags",
        "ec2:RegisterImage",
        "elasticbeanstalk:RemoveTags",
        "rds:RemoveTagsFromResource",
        "secretsmanager:UntagResource",
        "ec2:DeleteSnapshot",
        "ec2:DeleteTags",
        "kms:TagResource",
        "dynamodb:TagResource",
        "opsworks:TagResource",
        "es:AddTags",
        "logs:TagLogGroup",
        "ec2:StopInstances",
        "lambda:UntagResource",
        "elasticfilesystem:DeleteTags",
        "opsworks:UntagResource",
        "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
        "rds:AddTagsToResource",
        "transfer:UntagResource",
        "sqs:TagQueue",
        "elasticmapreduce:RemoveTags",
        "ec2:CreateImage",
        "resource-groups:Untag",
        "storagegateway:AddTagsToResource",
        "storagegateway:RemoveTagsFromResource",
        "cloudfront:TagResource",
        "ec2:DeregisterImage",
        "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags",
        "pi:DescribeDimensionKeys",
        "redshift:DeleteTags",
        "dynamodb:UntagResource",
        "iot:UntagResource",
        "polly:SynthesizeSpeech",
        "lambda:TagResource",
        "logs:StartQuery",
        "datapipeline:EvaluateExpression",
        "cognito-identity:UntagResource",
        "ec2:StartInstances",
        "ssm:RemoveTagsFromResource",
        "mq:DeleteTags",
        "logs:FilterLogEvents",
        "cognito-sync:QueryRecords",
        "clouddirectory:LookupPolicy",
        "kms:UntagResource",
        "eks:DescribeUpdates",
        "amplify:ListDomainAssociations",
        "workspaces:DeleteTags",
        "redshift:CreateTags",
        "states:TagResource",
        "es:ESHttpHead",
        "cognito-identity:TagResource",
        "sagemaker:DeleteTags",
        "ds:RemoveTagsFromResource",
        "es:RemoveTags",
        "acm:RemoveTagsFromCertificate",
        "ds:AddTagsToResource",
        "kinesisvideo:TagStream",
        "dms:AddTagsToResource",
        "gamelift:RequestUploadCredentials",
        "cloudwatch:TagResource",
        "elasticmapreduce:AddTags",
        "clouddirectory:BatchRead"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried with the below mentioned function

```
copyText(){
    let selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
      selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
      selBox.style.left = '0';
      selBox.style.top = '0';
      selBox.style.opacity = '0';
      selBox.value = this.jsonData;
      document.body.appendChild(selBox);
      selBox.focus();
      selBox.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
      document.body.removeChild(selBox);
    }
```

But it is not working as  **selBox.value** accepts only string. I don't want to convert the JSON to the string. I want to copy whole JSON to the clipboard. i found the answer to copy the string to the clipboard but I couldn't find a method to copy the whole JSON to the clipboard

Comment: hi follow this link it will be help you ..https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G8Y1B2HCGZZ4

Comment: how to copy it to the clipboard. @upinderkumar

Comment: i guess it is just copying the data to the text area, but i want to copy the data to the clipboard. @upinderkumar

Comment: you are creating a textarea the set the json value. I do the same,

Comment: refer this link : https://hackernoon.com/copying-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript-df4d4988697f

Comment: i tried the method by the website but it says **Retrieves or sets the text in the entry field of the textArea element.** i cant pass the json data here @upinderkumar

Comment: You cannot copy JSON objects as it is to clipboard. It has to be stringified. What issue are you facing with strings?

Comment: i used JSON.stringify() but it is not copying anything to the clipboard.@Saravana

Comment: I used JSON.stringify and after calling copyText() everything worked fine

Comment: can you please provide [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)  so it will be helpful for me to go through the code @StanislavBaturin

Comment: try running the code in your console: `function copyText(){
    let selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
      selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
      selBox.style.left = '0';
      selBox.style.top = '0';
      selBox.style.opacity = '0';
      selBox.value = JSON.stringify({anyJson:{a:"x"}});
      document.body.appendChild(selBox);
      selBox.focus();
      selBox.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
      document.body.removeChild(selBox);
    }
copyText()` @Santhosh

Comment: after copying the same code the clipboard is empty. it is not copying any data @StanislavBaturin

Comment: sorry, it only works for me in Google Chrome @Santhosh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
copyText(){
    let selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
      selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
      selBox.style.left = '0';
      selBox.style.top = '0';
      selBox.style.opacity = '0';
      selBox.value = JSON.stringify(this.jsonData);
      document.body.appendChild(selBox);
      selBox.focus();
      selBox.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
      document.body.removeChild(selBox);
    }
```

AS the **selBox.value** excepts the string value i Converted the JSON data to the string

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/copy-json-to-clipboard?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts). You can check the working example here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [clipboardjs](https://clipboardjs.com/) if you are ok with using a 3rd party package.

https://codepen.io/abgne-tw/pen/bewPKy

**js:**

```
https://codepen.io/abgne-tw/pen/bewPKy
new Clipboard('.abgne');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var abgne = document.querySelector('.abgne');

  abgne.setAttribute('data-clipboard-text', new Date());
  abgne.click();
});
```

**html:**

```
<button>Copy</buoon>

<div class="abgne"></div>
```

Comment: [Code Pen Link](https://codepen.io/deathpulse274/pen/eYYZJrx) check this example but on the clipboard I am getting only **[object Object]**

Comment: you need to stringify it first in your case: JSON.stringify(json)

Comment: how to implement the same in angular project @talhature

Comment: @Santhosh Although you can use clipboardjs in an angular project too, the best way would be using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-clipboard package. It is of course more Angular way. It leverages directives which makes things easier.

Comment: i got a solution without using the third party packages, anyway thanks for the help @talhatture

Comment: Nice, you can update your question with your custom solution then. :) An upvote from here

Comment: Even this solution works using the clipboard.js package.

Comment: code pen example [code Pen Example](https://codepen.io/deathpulse274/pen/eYYZJrx)